# SSRS Bring Total in to Matrix/Tablix

Tags: ssrs-2012

In the image below I need to calculate the two blank columns 'Percentage Total Pend' and 'Percentage Total NMI'. I need to divide the first column number by the total.

Ex: 1,326/4,491

I have researched how to get the Total value of the group inside and came across 'Inscope' but didn't fully understand the functionality. From what I have gathered this issue is because the Total or Subtotal is outside the grouping or Tablix. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP06z.png)

Comment: Just work with your query to get the percentage columns

Comment: It would be a lot more coding changes involved if I have to change the code in the datasource.